# Why doesn't my c++ code work?

Tags: c++

What have I done wrong with the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main ()
{

    int a;
    int b;
    int sum;

    cout << "Enter first number \n";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter second number \n";
    cin >> b;

    sum = a+b;
    cout << "The sum of both numbers is" << sum << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: missing `int` before `main`

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia It says about its hard life.

Answer (score 3):

Does the editor you are using tells errors, so the code is not executing? Or som exception rises? Or it is executing but nothing is shown? Please specify your problem accurately.

Anyway, you must use

```
int main ()
```

instead of

```
main()
```

Notice that your code returns a value. The last line of you code is:

```
return 0;
```

Thus, you must specify an int return type.

Comment: You must always specify a return type (or `void`) of a function in C++. Also, in the case of `main`, you can omit `return 0`, in which case `0` is returned implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Check your initial lines with this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()

{
```